# Reading raw audio samples from WAV files

Tags: ios, core-audio

What is the simplest way to obtain the raw audio samples (ideally as floats) from a WAV file without modifying the sample rate of the file?

I've followed the example at https://stackoverflow.com/a/4572990/1116197 but then I'm not sure how to extract the floats from `buffer`.   Just doing `buffer[n]` doesn't work.  According to `basicDescription.mFormatFlags` the file is `kAudioFormatFlagIsSignedInteger` and `kAudioFormatFlagIsPacked`

I've managed to do extract the data (as `float`s) using `ExtAudioFileRef` instead, but that requires specifying the output format you want, but I don't want to change the sampleRate. e.g. you can do

```
AudioStreamBasicDescription audioFormat;
audioFormat.mSampleRate = 44100;
audioFormat.mFormatID = kAudioFormatLinearPCM;
audioFormat.mFormatFlags = kLinearPCMFormatFlagIsFloat;
audioFormat.mBitsPerChannel = sizeof(Float32) * 8;
audioFormat.mChannelsPerFrame = 1; // Mono
audioFormat.mBytesPerFrame = audioFormat.mChannelsPerFrame * sizeof(Float32);  // == sizeof(Float32)
audioFormat.mFramesPerPacket = 1;
audioFormat.mBytesPerPacket = audioFormat.mFramesPerPacket * audioFormat.mBytesPerFrame; // = sizeof(Float32)


ExtAudioFileSetProperty(
    fileRef,
    kExtAudioFileProperty_ClientDataFormat,
    sizeof (AudioStreamBasicDescription), 
    &audioFormat
),
```

I guess I could obtain the files `AudioStreamBasicDescription` first using using `ExtAudioFileGetProperty`, but according to the Apple docs (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MusicAudio/Reference/ExtendedAudioFileServicesReference/Reference/reference.html) the property ID I need is `kExtAudioFileProperty_FileDataFormat` which is readonly - `A file’s data format. Value is a read-only AudioStreamBasicDescription struct.` - so I can't modify to it add `mFormatFlags = kLinearPCMFormatFlagIsFloat`

So I guess I could do the above, and the create a new ASBD and copy everything over, but it all seems  to be very over complicated so I wonder if I'm barking up the wrong tree entirely?  Is there a simpler way to do this?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you discovered, to do this you need to first get the file's data format and then create a client data format at the file's sample rate but with your desired sample size and type.  It really boils down to one extra function call which in the world of Core Audio isn't much.

Answer (score 2):

The most common .WAV files are just a 44 byte header followed by 16-bit or 2 byte little-endian raw PCM audio samples.  If you have one of those types of files, on a little-endian CPU (x86,ARM,etc.), you just need to skip the first 44 bytes, then read and convert short ints to floats.

Comment: Apple does NOT use 44 byte headers

Comment: iOS stores, plays and reads 44-byte header RIFF/.wav files just fine.  It might not create files in that format, depending on the API, but that's a different question.